# VBA how to paste in differente cell everytime i used the macro

Tags: vba, variables, filter, dynamic, range

im trying to make dynamic the paste, what i need is to pass a variable in
To do something like this:

```
myValue = InputBox("A7")
Range("myValue").Select
```

OR if somebody can tell me another way to approach this im open to suggestions:
(per example i was looking selecting a cell before running the macro but is not working, if somebody can give me any idea i will appreciate it thanks)

so far this is my code:

Sub copy_relative()

```
Sheets("Call Detail Record").Select
Range("D5:F27").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("CallDetailRecord").Select
Range("W7").Select   ' this is the value that i want  to change 
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

End Sub

Comment: Variables don't belong inside quotes.

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but `Sheets` is very literal, make sure you have the exact sheet name written correctly. I noticed that `Sheets("Call Detail Record")` and `Sheets("CallDetailRecord")` are different. One of these is likely going to raise a "subscript out of range" error